# Precision concerning double variable in C++

Tags: c++, precision

My problem is when I calculate one variable like this:

```
UXZ=(DRDe*sY*(Ux2 + Uy2) + cY*DRDt*Tau*(Ux2 + Uy2) + DRDx*Tau*Ux*Sqrt(1 + Ux2 + Uy2) + DRDy*Tau*Uy*Sqrt(1 + Ux2 + Uy2))/(Tau*Sqrt(1 - 1/(1 + Ux2 + Uy2)));
```

This value 1/(1 + Ux2 + Uy2) is set equal to (strictly) 1. Then, we have an error because the denominator is equal to 0.

However, the terms Ux2 and Uy2 are equal to (each) 1E-32. Consequently, the value is not strictly equal to 1.

I don't know how to set the precision on the calculation. 
Every variable in this equation are double, maybe I have to put them in long?

Edit : This calculation is implemented in a event generator, and Ux2 and Uy2 will change/increase during different times/iterations. We start with a very small value of Ux2 and Uy2, very close to 0 but not strictly 0. If we keep (1 + 1E-32 + 1E-32)=1. that fully break my code.

The important code for my question is this :

```
UXZ=XX/(YY*Sqrt(1 - 1/(1 + Ux2 + Uy2)));
```

I cannot change the value of Ux2 and Uy2 because that will change the physics problem under consideration.

Comment: please include a [mcve].

Comment: idclev means `(1 + Uxy2)/Uxy2` reaching infinity or such. That would trigger more help.

Comment: why do you need that much precision? `1 - 1E-32` is `1` for most practical purposes.

Comment: @JoopEggen no i don't, there is no such term in OPs code...

Comment: @idclev463035818 I meant if the OP tried some expressions, simplifying like Ux2+Uy2 as one variable, x going to 0 like 1/x going to infinity, more sensible things could be said. At least I needed time to just read the expression.

Comment: I find a way to solve my problem, this is to rewrite the equation in another way. This is just a mathematical way,. I can write the expression but that will not help to solve the problem in an informatical way.

Comment: You could try including <quadmath.h> and using the typedef __float128 - this is a 16 byte float with up to 36 digits of precision.

Comment: @james In a sense, that doesn't "solve" the problem, just moves it further away, Rearranging the expression to avoid a potential divide-by-zero (due to limited precision) is – IMHO – always going to be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "problem" term is:

```
SQRT( 1 - 1 / ( 1 + Ux2 + Uy2 ) )
```

Since `SQRT(a)` is identical to `SQRT(b*b * a) / b` (i.e. multiply *inside* the square-root by `b`-squared, and divide the result by `b`), then – using `(1 + Ux2 + Uy2)` for `b` – you get:

```
SQRT( (1 + Ux2 + Uy2)*(1 + Ux2 + Uy2) - (1 + Ux2 + Uy2) ) / (1 + Ux2 + Uy2)
```

which should evaluate to the same value, without triggering a divide-by-zero.

It would probably also be useful to bring out some of the common expressions (e.g. `1 + Ux2 + Uy2`) into variables.

---

To understand *why* you need to do this, you need to be looking into the area of [Numerical Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) (Wikipedia), in particular, [Generation and propagation of errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis#Generation_and_propagation_of_errors), which tackle the problem of representing arbitrary real numbers with the limited-precision schemes used in most computer languages.

I'm far from an expert in this, but at it's core, you have to recognise that while `1 - 1 / ( 1 + x )` will always be "valid", assuming `x` is at least a little-bit positive, in most computer implementations, `1 + x` will degenerate to exactly `1` for a small-enough `x`. Part of *Numerical Analysis* is recognising this, and reorganising *how* you perform a calculation to make better use of limited precision.

Comment: I guess also `(1 + Ux2 + Uy2) * (1 + Ux2 + Uy2) - (1 + Ux2 + Uy2)` => `(1 + Ux2 + Uy2) * (1 + Ux2 + Uy2  - 1)` => `(1 + Ux2 + Uy2) * (Ux2 + Uy2)`

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I did finally. That doesn't solve the problem informatically but that works.

Comment: @G.Sophys By "informatically" do you mean why does the original goes wrong, and why it is necessary to rearrange things?

Comment: @TripeHound Yes exactly